# Extending Stargazer

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, stargazer

I've long used `apsrtable` to quickly create model comparison tables, but I find it somewhat unattractive and clunky, so my dissertation tables were hand-coded tables with `\Sexpr` expressions. I was excited to find `stargazer`, but disappointed that some models I use aren't supported.

With `apsrtable` you can fairly easily extend a model by updating the `apsrtableSummary` and `ModelInfo` methods ([as in this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632754/843419)).

I've been looking (but haven't found) for a similar method to extend stargazer to the following models:

1. `lme`
2. `mlogit`
3. `spdep`

Anyone have any experience with this/know of how to do it?

Comment: Ugh, stargazer does not look like it was meant to be very extensible. Everything appears to be done in the `stargazer:::.stargazer.wrap` function with a bunch of `if`s to check for different models. It looks like a horrible mess to me.

Comment: Strange that the code is such a mess but the output is so gorgeous...

Comment: stargazer author here. Not a lot of extensibility at the moment, but planned for future releases. The messiness of the code is mostly a function of this being my first R project, and how things accumulated over time. :)

Comment: @Marek well, you're not off to a bad start. But it would be nice if there were a generic functions that you could define for different class types and you could decorate your class with whatever stargazer needed to know to render the plot. That would help relieve you of the responsibility of adding every possible class type into the same function.

Comment: Yep, working on it. Long to-do list, and not my only project, but hoping to get this kind of thing done by the end of the summer. If you have any specific ideas/suggestions, please e-mail me to the address specified in the package.

Comment: I'm not an R package author by any means, and there may be a better way to do stuff. But I really like how in `apsrtable` any model object can be fit by writing one or two method statements.

Comment: @Marek is `stargazer` on GitHub? (I've looked but haven't seen) Perhaps we in the community can help you move forward, because you have a very useful package, and an R library is usually not anybody's only project.

Comment: Not at the moment. Will consider. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Generics are available in ``texreg``. It's straightforward to add custom models. See section 6 of the [JSS article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v55/i08/).

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, I do not have a solution that will fit the critia given by OP. However the newest version of stargazer supports all of the models requested.

For refenrece see; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf
under the function "stargazer_models, page 13 and forward.