# How to put a glm() tidy into a lmList-like structure?

Tags: r, glm, tidy

For the sake of reproduction, I manipulated the iris data a bit:

```
data(iris)
View(iris)
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
library("tidyverse")
iris <- filter(iris, Petal.Width<1)
iris <- mutate(iris,
               Species2 = case_when(
                 Petal.Width == 0.1 ~ "setosa",
                 Petal.Width != 0.1 ~ "versicolor"))
```

I was able to do something like this for `lm()`:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species2) %>% 
do(tidy(lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width*Sepal.Length, data = .)))

fit1 <- nlme::lmList((Petal.Width) ~ Sepal.Width*Sepal.Length 
| Species2, data = iris)
do.call(stargazer, c(fit1, type = "text"))
```

I want to be able to do the same for glm():

```
iris %>% group_by(Species2) %>%
  do(tidy(glm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width*Sepal.Length, data = ., 
family=quasibinomial)))

fit1 <- nlme::lmList((Petal.Width) ~ Sepal.Width*Sepal.Length | 
Species2, data = iris)
# this needs to be a lmList for glm and glmlist() does not seem to work

do.call(stargazer, c(fit1, type = "text"))
```

Currently, the lm results come up when I use nlme::lmList. I want the glm results to be in the table.

Comment: Please show a small reprouducible example

Comment: `lme4::lmList()` can handle GLM fits, but unfortunately `stargazer` doesn't know about these objects ...

Comment: @BenBolker is there a method that is compatible with stargazer?

Comment: As I recall, with respect to its author, stargazer is a hot mess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910093/extending-stargazer . If it were me I would try `texreg` and/or `huxtable` ...

Comment: @BenBolker other packages do not seem to have desired layout

Comment: you may be stuck then ... you could submit a request to the `stargazer` maintainer ...

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution to this would be subsetting the GLM:

```
model = glm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width*Sepal.Length, data = iris, family=quasibinomial,
            subset = type == "setosa")

model1 = glm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width*Sepal.Length, data = iris, family=quasibinomial,
            subset = type == "veriscolor")

stargazer(model, model1)
```